# Excel: Check if multilined cell has text with more than 1 line (no VB)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As the title says: is there a way?
At the moment I use the **Length** formula but this is not very accurate because a cell with all "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" takes less space than a cell with all "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" (for instance) even if both cell in my example has a length of 20.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean with more than one line? Do you mean you want to know if the data spilled to the next line in a cell due to a fixed cell width or do you mean that you want to know if there is a newline char?

Comment: I have a multilined cell, at the beginning the cell is empty but it's completed during the process and it depends other factors there is more or less text into this cell.
Afterwards I remove the "empty lines" and I want to check if this cell is completed over more than one line to remove or not the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered using a "monospace" font on that column so that all characters occupy same space?
Then you can us the **Length** function as you want. Because "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" and "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" would take same width under a monospace font.

The "Consolas" is one such font.

Comment: Can't use this solution.